# PHP Variable in Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array where I need to add options to a select drop down menu like this `array('option_1' => 'Option 1', 'option_2' => 'Option 2', 'option_3' => 'Option 3')`
Manually typing this code, produces the desired output in the select menu:

```
<option value="option_1">Option 1</option>
<option value="option_2">Option 2</option>
<option value="option_3">Option 3</option>
```

Now, since these options are being pulled from a database, manually typing them isn't the answer, so I am grabbing the list of options, where each option is on it's own row in the database.

```
$options = explode("\n", get_option('field-options'));
$i = 1;
$select = "";
$prefix = "";
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $select .= $prefix . "'option_" . $i . "' => '" . $option . "'";
    $prefix = ', ';
    $i++;
}
```

When I `echo $select;` I get the correctly formatted list like this:

```
'option_1' => 'Option 1 ', 'option_2' => 'Option 2 ', 'option_3' => 'Option 3'
```

However, when I use `array($select)`, I get everything as the text value of one option:

```
<option value="0">
'option_1' => 'Option 1',
'option_2' => 'Option 2',
'option_3' => 'Option 3'</option>
```

How do I get $select variable to output correctly in the array.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The question seems unclear

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to do

Comment: If I understand you correctly you don't need that array at all. Just echo your `<option>`  directly.

Comment: you should probably tag it as WordPress related question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you assign array values dynamically.

```
$options = explode("\n", get_option('field-options'));
$i = 1;
$select = array();;
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $select["option_".$i] = $option;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build out the array syntax as you would type it. Instead, add onto the array like so:

```
<?php

$array = array();
$array['option_1'] = 'Option 1';
$array['option_2'] = 'Option 2';
$array['option_3'] = 'Option 3';
```

You now have an array `$array` with 3 items in it. You also don't need to use `$i` to track your position, you can use `$key => $value` notation, like so:

```
$select_options = array();
foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
    $select_options['option_' . $key] = $option;
}
```